# save email to safari local storage after login success

Tags: swift, macos, safari, safari-extension, safari-app-extension

I am trying to develop safari extension using swift safari services. The project is created from mac os and then safari extension. I am javascript developer but developing safari extension needed to use swift but I do not have any idea on how to save data in safari local storage. I looked at the following documentation but could not benefit from it

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions

here is the code

```
import SafariServices


class SafariExtensionViewController: SFSafariExtensionViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var passwordMessage: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailMessage: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var message: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var email: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: NSSecureTextField!
    static let shared = SafariExtensionViewController()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.preferredContentSize = NSSize(width: 300, height: 250)
        message.stringValue = ""
        emailMessage.stringValue = ""
        passwordMessage.stringValue = ""
    }


    @IBAction func userLogin(_ sender: Any) {
        let providedEmailAddress = email.stringValue
        let providedPassword = password.stringValue
        let isEmailAddressValid = isValidEmailAddress(emailAddressString: providedEmailAddress)
        self.message.stringValue = ""
        emailMessage.stringValue = ""
        passwordMessage.stringValue = ""
        if isEmailAddressValid && providedPassword.count > 0 {
            let parameters = ["email": providedEmailAddress, "password": password.stringValue]
            let URI = URL(string: "https://api.production.navihq.com/auth/sign_in")
            let session = URLSession.shared
            var request = URLRequest(url: URI!)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            do {
                request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

                guard error == nil else {
                    return
                }

                guard let data = data else {
                    return
                }

                do {
                    //create json object from data
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse { 
                            if (httpResponse.statusCode >= 200 && httpResponse.statusCode < 300) {
                                self.message.stringValue = "Login Successful"
                                // i want to store the email in safari local storage here
                            } else {
                                self.message.stringValue = "Invalid Credentials"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        } else {
            emailMessage.textColor = NSColor.red
            emailMessage.stringValue = "Invalid Email"
        }
    }

}
```

Not: I am not using IOS. I am using safariservices.

Answer (score 0):

Think you should use [Messaging capability](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/passing_messages_between_safari_app_extensions_and_injected_scripts) between Safari app extension and injected script. For example, send message from injected script to app ext. when `DOMContentLoaded` triggered and send the answer to it with needed data (currently email) to set into local storage of the browser by injected JS.

Hope it helps!